# syntax for sorting anonymous lists

Tags: scala, sorting

```
class P(val a: Int, val b: Int)
val listp = List[P](new P(2,1))
listp.sortWith( (p1, p2) => p1.b < p2.b )
listp.sortBy(p => (p.b))
```

`listp` is easy to sort

```
val list = List((2, 1))
list.sortWith( (a1, b1), (a2, b2) => b1 < b2)   // Too many arguements
list.sortWith( ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) => b1 < b2) // Not a legal formal parameter / <error> is already defined as <error>
list.sortBy((a, b) => (b))                      // wrong number of parameters expected
```

How do I sort `list`? All the method calls for list result in compile errors (I know I'm ignoring the return value, I just care about syntax).

I'm just looking for the syntax for the anonymous function. I know that it is possible to subclass `Ordered` like `Comparable` in Java.

**Edit** - This has it done for me, thanks for all answers:

```
list.sortWith( _._2 < _._2)
list.sortBy(_._2)
list.sortWith( (t1, t2) => t1._2 < t2._2 )
```

this is it explicitly

```
list.sortWith( (t1: Tuple2[Int, Int], t2: Tuple2[Int, Int]) => t1._2 < t2._2 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
scala> val list = List((2, 1),(5,-10))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (5,-10))

scala> list.sortWith{ case ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) => b1 < b2}
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((5,-10), (2,1))
```

Comment: if list is a List[Int, Int] why do we need pattern matching here? i feel that its just a way to avoid what the syntax should be.

Comment: It's not List[Int,Int], it's List[(Int,Int)]. The pattern match is required if you want to have an arguments-like way of extracting the values from the tuple. The other approach would be using `(l,r) => l._1<r._1`

Answer (score 9):

Given

```
val list = List((2,1), (3,4))
```

to sort by second element:

```
list.sortBy(_._2)
```

or much verbose:

```
list.sortBy { case(a,b) => b }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val list = List((2,1), (3,4))

list.sort(_._1 < _._2)

res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (3,4))
```

Comment: sweet! any idea what the syntax should be if i am avoiding the `_`

Comment: list.sort((a,b) => a._1 < b._2). Also see pedrofurla's answer.

Comment: `sort` is deprecated; don't use it